# How can one find the appropriate scaling for a sequence to converge to $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_i)$ be an iid sequence of random variables with $E[X_1] = \mu, Var(X_1) = \sigma^2.$ Let $\bar X_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_n}{n}.$ I want to find an appropriate scaling of $\bar X_n - \mu$ such that the sequence of the scaled random variables converges in distribution to $N(\mu, \sigma^2).$ How do I find the scaling ? I know the scaling such that the scaled sequence converges to $N(0,1)$ or $N(0,\sigma^2)$ but can not figure out the scaling needed to get convergence to $N(\mu,\sigma^2).$ I thank for your help.

Comment: You can't change the mean away from zero by scaling.

Comment: Thanks. But I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: The first comment points to the fact that if $X_n - \mu$ has mean $0$ then any scaling $a(X_n-\mu)$ will also have mean zero no matter what $a$ is. The scaling can only change the variance in this case. You need both a scaling *and* a shift $a(X_n-\mu) + b$ to get what you want (see the central limit theorem for what $a$ and $b$ should be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

Comment: Thanks. Starting then with $X_n$ or $\bar X_n, $ what should I do with it in terms of scaling so that the scaled sequence converges to $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ in distribution?

Comment: You could start with $\overline{X}_n-\mu$, which has mean zero and standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$. So $$\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$$ has mean zero and variance $1$. Then just add $\mu$.

Comment: Do you mean, $\frac{\bar X_n -\mu}{\sigma / \sqrt n}+\mu$ will converge to $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ ?